# push notification in android app

Tags: java, android, push-notification

i have developed one `Listview` app using soap `WebService` from `MySQL` database.Now one order is inserted on my database means that time this (new order is inserted) notify message is display on my android device.now i click the notification message means that time the app is run and display `Listview` successfully automatically when each and every new order is insert on my `MySQL` database.what methods am use here????please help me.

This is my `RetailerActivity.java` code:

```
public class RetailerActivity extends Activity {
ListView list;
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/customerData1";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "customerData1";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8089/XcartLogin/services/RetailerWs?wsdl";
private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        SoapPrimitive s = response;
        String str = s.toString();
        String resultArr[] = str.split("&");
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,resultArr));
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) { 

                String status =  parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                String[] status1  = status.split(" ");

                 String StrStatus = status1[1].toString();

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_STATUS, StrStatus);

                startActivity(in);            



            }
        });     
    } 




    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
 }
```

please here the `Listview` is successfully displayed.but the new order is inserted on my database means that time the new order is inserted `Notification` message is displayed on android device.now i have to click the notified meassage means it is display update `Listview`.how can i do???????? what methods i have to use here????

Comment: refresh ur listView using...ur listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()...and confirm that ur resultArr is changed

Comment: i wish to need push notification message on android device top.how can i do????any method is the...(for eg)c2dm or gcm

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the data in the new data in the ListView, then only thing that i think you will have to do is

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` // `adapter` is the instance of `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: i wish to need push notification message on android device top.how can i do????any method is the...(for eg)like c2dm or gcm

Comment: @user1676640 Very frankly speaking i have used the `parse.com` api to handle my push notifications, its easy and awesome.. the notification automatically comes to the top, clicking the notification will take you directly to the app, and if you want i can take you to some specific activity too, that you mention

Comment: yes exactly i need above concept only.where i can learn parse.com.please help me